# Most efficient way to clone an AWS RDS database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have 2 MySQL databases running on a server called X and Y, which both have identical content. A series of updates run throughout the day, which changes the content of X. At the end of the day, a process runs that compares the content of X with the content of Y (for various tables) in order to discover new rows, updated row data etc. Once the updates have been processed, `mysqldump` is used to dump X and then Y is overwritten with the dump. Both X and Y are now the same again, and the whole process repeats.

I'm investigating migration of these databases to Amazon RDS. What's the most efficient way to accomplish the process outlined above?

I understand that I can take a snapshot of a DB and restore it, but I think this is at the instance level only? That would mean I have to run 2 instances, which seems unnecessary. I don't have a problem running both databases on the same instance (I don't want to pay for more than one instance unnecessarily).

Do I just do what I'm doing now i.e. `mysqldump` X and restore it to Y, or is there some other method/shortcut that RDS provides?

Comment: RDS is one database per instance, so you'll have to pay for two instances if you want two databases.

Comment: However, _why_ do you want two databases, one of which remains static? Is this some form of read replica (RDS lets you create read replicas easily)? Or test data? Or something else? Without that information, it's impossible to give you a good answer.

Comment: I didn't realise that instances where limited to a single database. Well that answers my question then. Creating a snapshot and restoring to a new instance seems to be the most reasonable way to clone a database.

Comment: Don't confuse database instance with user-created databases `A DB instance is an isolated database environment running in the cloud. It is the basic building block of Amazon RDS. A DB instance can contain multiple user-created databases` [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.html)

Comment: The easiest method to clone an RDS database is to create a read replica and then promote that to a master.

Comment: RDS works at an instance level.  At a database level you are stuck with MySQL tools.  Depending on how complex your table structures are (and how many tables there are), you could extract the differenced rows into a temp table and then insert them into "Y".  This will work provided insert and delete are the only changes made.  In the case of updates, your best bet is to build an "ETL Layer", which consists of changed values only in a layer of tables build specifically as analogs of 'X' and then using them as staging. It's also called a Net Change Layer.

Comment: To create the Net Change Layer, build (I would do it in its own database) analog tables to those you want to keep with a layer_timestamp value and an action (I for Insert, U for Update, D for Delete) indicator column.  Build after insert / update / delete triggers on the tables to populate these analog interface tables (for each row).  use those tables the same way an ETL process would to populate "Y".  To me, the key is "two databases on my server" singular.

Comment: @RTF - I may have misread your question. If you mean individual databases in a single server then yes, RDS can support multiple databases. In that case, all comments about replication are moot, and your best option is probably a `create table ... as` statement (since it would not require moving data over the network), followed by recreating indexes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider migrating to RDS Aurora for MySQL.

It supports native copy-on-write clones of the entire database (meaning server instance, not schema) **without** the need to make an actual "copy."

Copy-on-write means the "original" server and the "clone" share the same physical disk (called an Aurora Cluster Volume, which is replicates itself twice across 3 availability zones, using a 4/6 quorum), with both servers sharing the same disk blocks *until* one of them makes a change... which is when the copy action actually occurs ("on write").  So, you only use as much storage as is required to store your original working data set plus changes that occurred after cloning.

No server is the master in such a setup -- they all operate independently after cloning.  I suspect that I'm not doing this innovation justice with my description -- it involves quite a bit of dark magic.  See the write-up (with illustrations of copy-on-write): 
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Managing.Clone.html

Aurora is compatible with MySQL 5.6.  To be more precise, Aurora *is* MySQL 5.6, with MyISAM removed and InnoDB heavily rewritten to optimize performance and work with the replicated Aurora Cluster Volume storage technology.

Comment: I do like the sound of Aurora, but I think what your suggesting defeats the purpose of what I try to accomplish. If every write to X carries over to Y transparently, then I have no way to detect what has changed in X over the day. I'm essentially doing a `diff` between the 2 DBs at the end of the day.

Comment: Writes do not carry over transparently, @RTF.  That would be replication.  This is cloning. The two running copies are logically isolated. The *divergence* is what is handled transparently, here.  When a data block on the server X changes, that same block is left unchanged on server Y.  The magic comes in because for each *unchanged* block, both servers are actually reading from the *same* block.  When one of them changes something, it is now allocated a *different* block, with neither server aware that for unchanged blocks, they're reading the same physical data.

Comment: The point of this solution is that you can make a "copy" of a running database at a *logical* level.  Rather than physically copying all the data and loading it onto a new server, there's just a magical point in time established... after which... every subsequent write changes only the data that is visible to the system that made the change, and not to the other one.  It accomplishes your objective of creating a live point in time snapshot on a second running server.

Comment: Slightly confused. So, if I add a new row to table T in database X, I can still query database Y to discover that new row a few hours later, yes? And if so, how do I get the 2 DBs in sync again?

Comment: No.  They permanently diverge, so you don't *technically* get them in back sync... instead, you discard Y and then create a new Y whenever you want -- a process that is easily automated... e.g. (from the link, above) `aws rds restore-db-cluster-to-point-in-time 
--source-db-cluster-identifier my-cluster-x --db-cluster-identifier my-cluster-y --restore-type copy-on-write --use-latest-restorable-time`.  Note that "restore" does not change the original, it "restores" it to a new system.  Also, you would need to script the destruction of the old Y, first.

Comment: With my current setup (e.g. 2 DBs on the same MySQL server) I have a few queries that perform joins on tables in both of the DBs (to discover changes as efficiently as possible). Am I right in thinking that this kind of query would not work with the solution you propose?

Comment: No, this would not work with 2 DBs on the same server.  This is for two different servers.  For two DBs on the same server, dump and load is the canonical and simplest solution, or you could write or find a tool that can do a one-shot synchronization of tables.

Answer (score 62):

Since the title is concerned AWS instance migration the best way is with my case (can be vary to others case)

1. Goto -> https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds
2. Select your DB Instance
3. Actions -> Take Snapshot
4. Goto -> https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds
5. Snapshots from left pane
6. select your snapshot just created
7. Action -> Restore Snapshot

After above steps you will be redirected to RDS instance creation page fill out required fields as per requirements and you are done with migration :D

Comment: I don't who voted down but as far as my experience is concerned with AWS this is the most best way to do migration or clone i did many times

Comment: I agree @mansur-ali . In my opinion, this is a better way to do it. Less changes of mistakes as well.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late in the day but I have just managed to do this by (1) creating a database back up to S3 and then (2) restoring the backup from S3, i.e.

a. Create database back up in S3

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database @source_db_name = '<database-name-goes-here>'
                                 ,@s3_arn_to_backup_to = 'arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name-goes-here>/<backup-filename-goes-here>.bak'
                                 ,@overwrite_S3_backup_file = 1;
```

b. Wait for the task to complete. You can execute the following SQL to check this

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status @db_name='<database-name-goes-here>';
```

c. When the lifecycle is "SUCCCESS" you can then restore from the S3 bucket using the following command

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database @restore_db_name='<new-database-name-goes-here>'
                                  ,@s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name-goes-here>/<backup-filename-goes-here>.bak';
```

d. Again you can monitor the status of the restore with the following SQL command

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status @db_name='<database-name-goes-here>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could setup AWS MySQL RDS instance as a slave of an external master.

After loading a full dump to RDS, Call the stored procedure [mysql.rds_set_external_master](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_external_master.html) like this:

```
mysql> call mysql.rds_set_external_master ('10.10.3.2', 3306, 'replica', 'password', 'mysql-bin-changelog.122', 108433, 0);
```

Then start the replication by doing:

```
mysql> call mysql.rds_start_replication;
```

Once you have data in sync you can promote RDS to master by doing:

```
mysql> call mysql.rds_stop_replication;
mysql> call mysql.rds_reset_external_master;
```

By doing this either using your external X or Y servers, the AWS RDS behaves like a replica, the one you could use as your future master if required.

Comment: Mixing dumps and replication like this is almost guaranteed to give you problems: either you'll be missing rows (because the dump is before the current binlog position) or you'll be getting key errors (because the dump is ater the current binlog position). RDS makes it easy to create replicas without dumpfiles.

Comment: @kdgregory what part of "I'm investigating migration of these databases to Amazon RDS. What's the most efficient way to accomplish the process outlined above?" you didn't understand?

Comment: My most abject apologies, I didn't realize that breaking the database was considered efficient. And to be honest, I think that the one click "create a read replica" is far more efficient than manually loading dumps. But hey, each to their own.

Comment: @kdgregory your objection is noted, but the systems under discussion are not currently using RDS at all, and this answer addresses a migration strategy.  Only the initial dump and load, interim replication, and final promotion of RDS are discussed here.  After that... yes, RDS provides a simple mechanism.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I think you're missing my point, although thankfully you avoid the sarcasm of *nbari*. The MySQL docs have a very explicit procedure to go through to keep dumps and binlogs in sync, and this answer _does not mention that process_. If you don't follow the process, you're going to run into problems when you try to sync the machines. Maybe you'll run into visible problems, maybe you'll suffer invisible data loss. And leaving out the complete process, or assuming that the OP knows it, is IMO extremely dangerous and worthy of a downvote.

Comment: @kdgregory that is a reasonable concern, and the answer as written may indeed assume too much knowledge on the part of the reader.  Correctly configuring replication is, by its very nature, a delicate operation, and your point is correct that the risk of broken replication or silent data loss is real if you don't follow the correct process.