# Safest way to clone an AWS RDS Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS Instance (MySQL) used in production for a variety of apps, my goal is to clone the entirety of it so i can use the clone to perform upgrades to different versions of MySQL. Is there a way to achieve this without any big downtimes or the risk of losing any sort of data?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46820661/14843902) of use?

Comment: The 2nd answer from the post does address this particular issue better than the first one, but i want a more in dept answer that can tell me if that process involves any risk or downtime, although i have to say im down to try those steps in another RDS Instance, thanks.

Comment: Is there something wrong with creating a snapshot and then creating a new instance from that snapshot? If you need the data to stay up to date, look at their database migration services.